# How to create a DOC or RTF file in LUA language?

Tags: lua

I have a file to create. Via com connection?

local file = io.open("myfile.txt", "w")
file:close()

Comment: Alternative: create a docx file, for which you would only need non-GUI, in-process libraries (vs out-of-process COM Word automation): a .NET binding such as NLua or Lua Interface and OpenXML. Or, even HTML or XML are alternatives.

Comment: No, I need it on LUA

Comment: NLua and Lua Interface are accessible in Lua, just like LuaCom.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use something like [LuaCom](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaCom) library, which provides Component Object Model binding for Lua.

Comment: Thank.
I started to understand, but the problem constantly arises.
You can not use the Russian language: an error with the encoding in file. For example:

Comment: local fileName = "myfile3.doc"
local FileWrite
FileWrite = io.open(fileName, "w")
FileWrite:write("фывф", '\n')
FileWrite:close()

Comment: require('luacom')
excel = luacom.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = true
wb = excel.Workbooks:Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
for i=1, 10 do
 ws.Cells(i,1).Value2 = "фывф"
end

Comment: You may add a separate question for it, as it's out of scope for this one.

Comment: Already answered the question there; if this answer works for you, you may accept it.